# How does a Chrome Extension 'listen' for all iFrames on host page to complete loading?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome Extension wraps a toolbar around specific URLs.

It adjusts the size of the host page - to make room for the toolbar.

The Extension Content Script is injected into every frame (not just top).

Some pages with which I want my Chrome Extension to work have iFrames that take a while to load content.

Some of these pages resize when the iFrame content finally finishes loading. How do I listen for iFrames to complete loading before I adjust the size of the parent page?

I believe I'll need to have each content script that is injected into the page communicate through the Background Script to the parent page...but I do not understand how to specific, from a content script injected into an iFrame on a page, that the destination for the message is the top-level content script that can then adjust the size of the parent webpage.

Any suggestions/direction appreciated!

Update:
Riffing on helpful answers/suggestions...

I don't understand how background will know how many iFrames there are and when the page is truly finished loading. I modified the suggestion below to both listen for the completion of a completed iFrame load AND then query the active Tab to see whether loading is complete...Not sure if this is redundant...

Then background calls the content script to ask it to resize the window.

This is showing some promise but I have to rewire a few other things to be sure it will work.

Thoughts on this approach?

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(info => {
  console.log('WEB navigation complete...?', info);
  // if (info.frameId) {
    // chrome.tabs.sendMessage(info.tabId, {cmd: 'frameLoaded'}, {frameId: 0});
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      console.log('Message current window to resize the window...', tabs[0].status);
      if (tabs[0].status === "complete"){
        try {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {method: "resizeWindow"});
        } catch (err){
          console.log('Could not message content script because: ' + err);
        }
      }
    });
  // }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sender` in [onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) listener in the background script to identify the tab of the message (`sender.tab.id`) and re-send it to the top content script (frameId 0).

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (msg.cmd === 'frameLoaded') {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, msg, {frameId: 0});
  }
});
```

---

However it might be better to use [chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCompleted) in the background script to detect an iframe's load event without the need to run content scripts inside the iframes.

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(info => {
  if (info.frameId) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(info.tabId, {cmd: 'frameLoaded'}, {frameId: 0});
  }
});
```

- `frameId: 0` sends to the main page's content script, not to iframes
- don't forget to add `"permissions"` in manifest.json as indicated in the documentation

---

Another possibility is to use a `load` event listener inside the iframes' content scripts and DOM messaging via `top.postMessage` ([more info](https://devdocs.io/dom/window/postmessage)), but some sites will spam errors in console because they already use `message` with certain properties inside that you can't anticipate and provide. Some sites may even break because of that, theoretically.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful and detailed answer.

I had been hammering away through the content script and forgot to look at the power of background...where I am already listening for tab updates etc. So I have the permission already in place.

However, after experimenting a bit, I don't understand how background would know that the entire page (with perhaps 3 iFrames) is loaded. Each iFrame communicates separately with background?

Updating my question with what I'm trying...

Comment: Your new code is assuming it's always the active tab that gets updated, but it should use `info.tabId` (see the documentation). However, checking tab's `status` won't reflect iframes so I think the correct approach is to recalculate styles/positions each time you receive the `frameLoaded` message from an iframe.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm! 

I'm assuming active tab because I only want to resize on the tab the user is viewing. I have a handler for tab updated - for tab switches.

To clarify: the suggested code and my implementation have the _background_ messaging the content script ('frameLoaded')...so you're saying:
* Background watches iFrames get updated - waits for load
* Background messages top level content script to resize - on each iFrame completed load
* Content script on top level of target tab listens and then runs the resize logic.

Comment: If you have a listener for onActivated you can store the active tab id in a global variable so that webNavigation listener can compare info.tabId to that id. Either way, query() is unreliable/wrong here. A more reliable alternative would be to send the message without any checks and simply let the tab handle it by checking `document.visibilityState`